# @click calling a methods not workings in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm learning Vue.JS since some days, i'm just tryna doing an app that add a chip on click on a button. The created chips should get the value on of an input as name.
I have created a method that (normally), should create this chip. It's not even calling the method and i don't know why, i've tried to console.log something at the beginning of the methods to check it...

Thanks all !

My App.vue :

```
<template>
  <v-app id="whole_container">
    <v-content id="main_container">
      <v-row id="main_row">
        <v-col class="hellocol" id="chips">
          <customChip name="Louis"></customChip>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="hellocol" id="chipField">
          <addChip></addChip>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import customChip from './components/chip.vue';
import addChip from './components/addChip.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    customChip,
    addChip
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

My AddChip file :

```
<template>
    <div>  
        <v-text-field id="newChip" :outlined="true" label="Entrez un nom" placeholder="Michel" v-model="currentName"></v-text-field>
        <p>Je m'appelle {{ currentName }}</p>
        <chipButton @click="addChip( currentName )"></chipButton>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import chipButton from './button.vue';

export default {
    data: () => ({
        currentName: ""
    }),
    components: {
        chipButton,
    },
    methods: {
        addChip: function(name) {
            console.log(name);
            let actualChips = document.getElementById('chips');
            let newChip = document.createElement('customChip');
            newChip.name = name;
            actualChips.appendChild('newChip');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to target the click on the HTML element of the chipButton component, instead of `@click=` use `@click.native=` to listen to events on the native element and not the component element.

If you really need to listen to the `click` event on the component yo have to emit that event the component (like if the event listener is on a child element):

```
// chipComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$emit('click')">Something</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

But I would go with the `@click.native=` directive unless you need something specific.

Answer (score 0):

Any template tag here `<chipButton>` has been replaced with template contents so if you write anything like `<chipButton @click="addChip( currentName )">` will be replaced with its template content and rest of attribute will vanished.

This is the example to understand as I said above.

```js
Vue.component('test',{
  template:`<div @click="childClick">Click here to check which methods is calling</div>`,
  methods:{
    childClick: function(){
      alert('childClick');
    }
  }
})
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#niklesh',
  data:{
    name:'Niklesh Raut'
  },
  methods:{
    parentClick: function(){
      alert('parentClick');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="niklesh">
  <test  @click="parentClick"></test>
</div>
```

Solution 1 : Either you need to put your method inside your child component.

Solution 2 : Or just wrap up with any tag like `div`.

```js
Vue.component('test',{
  template:`<div @click="childClick">Click here to check which methods is calling</div>`,
  methods:{
    childClick: function(){
      alert('childClick');
    }
  }
})
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#niklesh',
  data:{
    name:'Niklesh Raut'
  },
  methods:{
    parentClick: function(){
      alert('parentClick');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="niklesh">
  <div @click="parentClick"><test></test></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if the component tag is replaced with the template's html of that component that doesn't mean the `@click` event listener is lost. That is not what causes the issue.

Comment: @arieljuod: Untill you post fixed event with `.native` as you suggested,  Vue will not take care of any event.